# The notification won't be "On Going"

Tags: android, notifications

I want to show an on going notification. but It's still shows up in Notifications part.
I used a custom layout for my notification.

here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int icon = android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Hi", when);
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.custom_notification);
    notification.contentView = contentView;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Edit:
You can see this image to see what I want to do.
http://backcountrynavigator.com/wp-content/uploads/screenshots/download_ongoing_notification.png

Comment: A notification flagged as "ongoing event" is still a notification. That's why it shows up in the notification list. It's basically a sticky notification that cannot be cleared from the list with the clear button.

Comment: What do you mean "but It's still shows up in Notifications part". Don't you expect it a notification to show up there?

Comment: @NobuGames I think that's Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR that makes the notification un clearable.

Comment: @PatrickKafka I will add a photo to clear my question.

Comment: @NimaAhmadi I stand corrected, sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start ongoing notifications with `Service.startForeground()` besides `NotificationManager.notify()`

EDIT: I also recommend that you use Notification.Builder instead of new Notification(), and then use [setOngoing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29), just to keep it clean.

Comment: Thanks!
I think I need to make a Service for my app before thinking about the notification.
I'm going to support down to API level 8 but notification builder is not supported there!

Comment: @NimaAhmadi you can use Android Compatibility Library if you want to support Level 8 API 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html